# MySQL without "sudo"

Tags: mysql, command-line, sudo

I need to invoke the `sudo` command every time I want to use MySQL through command-line in Ubuntu 16.04. If `sudo` is not invoked, I get the following error message:

```
$ mysql -u anyuser -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

My `anyuser` is already created in "mysql". I would like to avoid the use of `sudo`.

Comment: Check the owner of `/tmp/mysql.sock`. I think you did not give it the proper access rights.

Comment: If mysql is running on the standard port, a workaround could be to run mysql with `--host=localhost --port=3306`.

Comment: @Willem: The socket file "mysql.sock" never gets created even if I run "mysql" with the "sudo" command.

Comment: @R.Ilma: but that file is not created by running `mysql`: it is the *daemon* that creates this file: so you should run the daemon properly. For instance `sudo service mysql restart`.

Comment: Did you run the `mysql_secure_installation` step when installing?

Comment: @George: Yes, I did `sudo mysql_secure_installation`.

Comment: Perhaps you should re-run that step again! Obviously it's not recognizing your authority to create that file

Comment: Well, it seems that "anaconda" has a "mysql" which it is messing up with the one installed with "apt-get install ...". If I do this `$ which mysql`, I get
`/home/rilma/anaconda3/bin/mysql`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a careful inspection, I found two "mysql" in my system: One located at the Anaconda's bin directory and another in "/usr/bin/". The "mysql" installed in the System's bin directory creates a socket file at "/var/run/mysqld/". My systems points to the "mysql" at the Anaconda's bin directory by default, thus I solved the issue by creating a symbolic link as follows:

```
$ ln -s /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock /tmp/mysql.sock
```